# python module for document templating mange

Tags: python, module

Can anyone reccomend python module for manipulating documents. I need module which can replace any vars in text( i.e. $$TITLE$$) without format lossing. Module need for Microsoft Word 2003/2007, OpenDocuments.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried it myself, but https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx seems to be what you are looking for.   Has not been updated in a while, but it is old Word versions you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is no single python module that can generically manipulate both Microsoft and OpenOffice document formats.

That said, both Microsoft Office and OpenOffice (can) use XML to store their documents. For Office 2003 XML is optional, but from 2010 it is the default.

So you can follow two approaches:

1. quick-and-dirty
   Using an XML toolkit and XPath, select (XML) text nodes in the document. Run your replacement routine on each text node.
2. neat-but-slow
   Study the XML format of each document type. Using an XML toolkit and XPath, select the nodes that will contain (document) text. Run your replacement routine on each of the text nodes.

I would start with quick-and-dirty and see how far it gets you. Then if you see that nodes are changed that you did not want to be changed, you can add add-hoc measures to prevent that based on studying the XML formats.

Comment: Ah, then have a look here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/16/python-and-microsoft-office-using-pywin32/